# Failed to load next.config.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

After cloning the [repository](https://github.com/colbyfayock/next-wordpress-starter) I created and set my `.env.local` file, ran `npm i` then ran `npm run dev`. The server starts, env is loaded from `.env.local` however it immediately fails prompting me with the following:

```
error - Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
Error: Not supported
    at Object.loadConfig [as default] (C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\rebuild\node_modules\next\dist\server\config.js:399:74)
    at async NextServer.loadConfig (C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\rebuild\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:110:22)
    at async NextServer.prepare (C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\rebuild\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js:92:24)
    at async C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\rebuild\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:126:9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! rebuild@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the rebuild@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-29T19_47_30_427Z-debug.log
```

The NextJS documentation says: `See the error message in your terminal where you started next to see more context.` however all it is telling me is Not Supported.

I'm not familiar with the error and was looking for guidance.

Comment: It's happening to me too. Post it as an answer if you've found one. It used to run fine on windows. I just installed Ubuntu, and this exact error pops up.

Comment: Perhaps that's because of the breaking change of [Next.js 12](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12)? The repo was updated four days ago. You can probably try downgrading.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling Node and everything related to it. Reinstalled with Node v14.0.0 and it seemed to work.

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Had the same issue on ubuntu. I upgraded nodesj to the latest version (see https://askubuntu.com/a/480642). Then it worked again.

Comment: If you need to change your node version a lot, I recommend using nvm. Instead of needing to uninstall and install another version, you can just use one command to alter your node version

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: Worked for me I was using v12^ I reinstalled to 18^ it worked

Comment: I'm using node v10, but upgrading to v14 works for me, and i not needed install jemalloc and sharp. Builds run success!

Answer (score 17):

I solved this by upgrading to the latest version of nodeJS

Answer (score 5):

This error `Error: Not supported` is likely coming up because the installed [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) version is not supported by the used [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) version.

e.g. [Next.js v12 doesn't support Node.js v10](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12):

> The minimum Node.js version has been bumped from 12.0.0 to 12.22.0, which is the first version of Node.js with native ES modules support

This version discrepancy can arise for **several reasons**, sometimes quite unexpected, and also seemingly "out of nowhere", because not only a "wrong" Node.js version can be installed, but also different Node.js versions can be installed in different paths.

#### Solutions:

*(Note that after the below solutions you also might need to delete the folders `.next` and `node_modules`, and re-install the node modules again, e.g. `yarn` or `npm install`).*

##### 1. different computer

If you pull the repository on a different computer, where a different Node.js version is installed:

**Solution:** update Node.js to the supported version.

##### 2. different environment

If you build the repository inside a different environment, where a different Node.js version is referenced (e.g. in Webstorm vs. a separate Terminal):

**Solution:** make sure you are using the correct environment, or use the correct path to Node.js, or update Node.js.

##### 3. different build commands

If you use different build commands, which do or do not specify a (absolute) path to a specific node.js installation:

- e.g. `/usr/bin/node ...` --> use absolute path to specific node.js installation.
- e.g. `node ...` --> use node installation as specified in the $PATH environment variable, e.g. `/home/(username)/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1/bin/node`.

**Solution:** Modify the build script to use the correct path to Node.js, or update the Node.js version under the used path.

##### 4. broken build setup

If for some reason the build setup in Webstorm gets lost or breaks, which apparently can happen sometimes, e.g. when switching branches:

(You can verify this by trying to build inside a separate terminal.)

**Solution:** Fix the build setup in Webstorm to use the correct Note.js path, or update Node.js under the used path.